# SQL query with multiple Joins using CodeIgniter active records

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this working query:

```
$q = $this->db->query('SELECT u.name  FROM users u 
JOIN user_group ug ON u.id = ug.user_id 
JOIN groups g ON g.id = ug.group_id WHERE ug.group_id = "4" ');
```

And I want to replace it with aactive record. I come up with something like this but obviously it doesn't work :

```
$this->db->select('name');
   $this->db->from('users');
   $this->db->join('user_group', 'user_group.user_id = users.id);
   $this->db->join('groups', 'groups.id = user_group.group_id');
   $q = $this->db->get();
```

Thanks 
Leron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forget add `where` clause. And there was single quote missing.

```
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('user_group', 'user_group.user_id = users.id');
$this->db->join('groups', 'groups.id = user_group.group_id');
$this->db->where('user_group.group_id', 4);
$q = $this->db->get();
```